# Is there any way we can connect AWS Lambda Function (Python) to an existing external PostgresSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and am looking to connect my external postgres database hosted on Amazon EC2 to a lambda function (python) which gets triggered when a particular data in inserted to database. I searched many article but they used Postgres instance in AWS RDS and not exsiting external database. 
Thank You in advance.

Comment: You just need to make a network connection between Lambda and your EC2 instance possible. If you're running Lambda in a different VPC, it will need outgoing network support, for which you'll need to set up a NAT gateway in the VPC. If it's within the same VPC, you shouldn't need that. On your EC2 instance, you'll need to open the port appropriately to allow incoming connections. Preferably you'll want to use security groups to limit connectivity to the EC2 Postgres port as coming from Lambda.

Comment: @Devesh: Could you please clarify... The PostgreSQL database is running on an Amazon EC2 instance (not Amazon RDS), is that correct? And you wish to trigger an AWS Lambda function when particular data is inserted into that PostgreSQL database? If so, are you aware of other examples of how inserting data into a PostgreSQL database can trigger a call to an external service? You could use tools like Tibco that probably run off Change Data Capture, but I couldn't see any native PostgreSQL functionality to trigger external code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution described in the following AWS blog should work  **with any PostgreSQL**, and is not limited to RDS:

- [Stream changes from Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL using Amazon Kinesis Data Streams and AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/)

They even **explicit** write:

> The database can be either Amazon RDS or **any installation of PostgreSQL**.

The key component of the solution is the use of [wal2json](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) plugin for postgresql:

> wal2json is an **output plugin** for logical decoding. It means that the plugin have access to tuples produced by INSERT and UPDATE. Also, UPDATE/DELETE old row versions can be accessed depending on the configured replica identity. Changes can be consumed using the streaming protocol (logical replication slots) or by a special SQL API.

Using the `wal2json`, changes to postgresql would be infested to **Kinesis Data Streams**, and then consumed by **lambda function**.